# What the heck is happening to my image?

Tags: css, image, hover, pixel

An image, at the bottom of my page is a bit pixelated for some reason. when you hover over it, it becomes normal again and it also gets bigger. This also happens when you 'unhover" it. I tried changing to position to: fixed. that helped, but I don't want the position to be fixed. **Just try it out on the snippet, you'll understand my problem.**

*(I am using safari, macOS)*

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/dnsvnr/csLoeaLb/1/

CSS

```css
.insta {
position: absolute;
z-index: 6;
top: 0px;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, 0);
filter: brightness(0);
transition: filter .3s;
}

.insta:hover {
filter: brightness(0.5);
transition: filter .3s;
}
```

```html
  <a href="http://www.instagram.com/dnsvnr" target="_blank">
<img src="http://www.dnsvnr.com/instagram-white-300x300-2.png"  class="insta" width="15" height="15"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using big images and they are blurry when downsizing. Try to add:

```
 img{
  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;         /* Firefox */
  image-rendering:   -o-crisp-edges;         /* Opera */
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;/* Webkit (non-standard naming) */
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;  /* IE (non-standard property) */
 }
```